# Python file-type association won't change from command prompt

Tags: python, windows

I recently accidentally changed the file type association for .py files to .cmd on Windows 7.  The option to change the association under the properties doesn't appear.  Is there a way to change this back to Python3.4? Thanks!

Comment: How did you accidentally change the file type association? Are you comfortable working with the `regedit` program to change the Windows registry directly? Do you want a double-click of a `.py` file to run the file, open it for editing, or something else? What is the location of your `py.exe` if it exists, or `python.exe` or `python3.exe` or `pythonw.exe`?

Comment: When I originally double clicked the file, it opened up the Python command terminal, from which I could launch the program, but I'd like to be able to double click on the file and have the program launch.  I've worked with regedit in the past but I figured I'd ask in here what specifically I should change so I don't break anything!  Both python.exe and pythonw.exe are located in C:\Python34.